# How to programmatically fire a dblclick event defined with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, events, double-click

For JS Unit test, I need to check that a double-click behaves as expected. The issue is that the event was registered via element.addEventListener. And for some reason, in this case, element.ondblclick() does not work.
HTML:

```
<input type="image" src="pic.jpg" id="aa"/>
```

Javasript:

```
document.getElementById('aa').addEventListener("dblclick", function(){alert('aa')});
document.getElementById('aa').ondblclick();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prZKy/

If you double click on the image, it works, but the ondblclick() in the javascript does not work.

Anyone has an idea on how to do it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent

Comment: interestingly, this works - http://jsfiddle.net/MNx9K/
why?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `dispatchEvent` to programatically trigger events:

```
var event = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
document.getElementById('aa').dispatchEvent(event);
```

See the section "Triggering built-in events" on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events).

Comment: @Nenotlep Because IE9 sucks ass and doesn't recognize the `dblclick` event. You need to hack yourself a `click` handler which sets a timeout, faking a double-click. [Yuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408714/double-click-using-ie).

Comment: how to dispatchEvent to a coords instead of getElement?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var doubleClickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
doubleClickEvent.initEvent('dblclick', true, true);
e.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(doubleClickEvent); // inside method
```