# How to make a dblclick event in javascript?

Tags: javascript

To call a click event on an element `element.click()`

But how to do it with `dblclick`?

Is there an existing built-in function in javascript similar to `element.click()`?

Comment: Downvoted as the first hit on a google search for `javascript double click event` gives you the syntax.

Comment: @adamdc78 I dont want to catch the double click event listener (e.g. `element.addEventListener("dblclick",function(e){console.log(e)},false);` ). I want to call it. and the results on google does not answer my question.

Comment: Also from the first hit on a google search: [How to programmatically fire a dblclick event defined with addEventListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399215/how-to-programmatically-fire-a-dblclick-event-defined-with-addeventlistener)

Comment: @adamdc78 that result didn't come out for me, but its helpful thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `ondblclick`:

http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yrL8r6qd/

```
var p = document.getElementById('dbl');
p.ondblclick = function (){
  this.innerHTML = 'dbl';  
};
p.ondblclick(); // if you want to "trigger" the event, call it like so
```

---

When using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), you need to use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent):

http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yrL8r6qd/2/

```
var p = document.getElementById('dbl');

p.addEventListener('dblclick',function(e){
    this.innerHTML = 'dbl';
});

p.dispatchEvent(new Event('dblclick'));
```

Comment: What if my code used `element.addEventListener("dblclick",function(e){console.log(e)},false);` how do I do it? `ondblclick()` is not working for me.

Comment: @Deadpool updated my answer, let me know if you need any help! Also this can help you out some, definitely worth a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 1):

```
object.ondblclick=function(){myScript};
```

or

```
object.addEventListener("dblclick", myScript);
```