# perform double click on Div

Tags: javascript, powershell

I have problem, I Tried Alot of things.
Look here:

that is my Div element that i try to perform double click

[image]

Ok what did i tried.

1. Try this [tutorial](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/powershell-abcs-j-is-for-javascript) that code looks like that [That](http://pastebin.com/qyzqCtEy) (right now i dont try send any id i just do const in function but the error no there so right now less care)

> Error: "'document' is undefined

2. I already asked in the [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004164/perform-doubleclick-on-element-that-have-that/35004330#35004330) how to perform dblclick in javascript
   it worked.... in The console, but not in the PowerShell, in Powershell:

**in that example:** Event no exist so i cant even try that

```
var evt = new Event('dblclick');

var button = document.getElementById('myButton');

// This is where the magic happens
button.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

**in that [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399215/how-to-programmatically-fire-a-dblclick-event-defined-with-addeventlistener):**

There no MouseEvent so same cant even try that one.

**in that example:**

It more complicate, the $ie.docuemnt not contains the createEvent function.
And the Firevent not working.

[Here the code i try](http://pastebin.com/ahJ4vb5Q)

Please help.

```
var event; // The custom event that will be created

if (document.createEvent) {
  event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  event.initEvent("dataavailable", true, true);   
} else {
  event = document.createEventObject();
  event.eventType = "dataavailable";   
}


event.eventName = "dataavailable";

if (document.createEvent) {
  element.dispatchEvent(event);   
} else {
  element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);   
}
```

**Any more idiea to try, every thing is good :)**

Comment: You linked to a private paste on pastebin. Please just post your code in the question instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you didnt notice it, change it.

i cant post it here, when i make it on <code> tag it wont mark it as code tag on the preview so i paste in pastebin

Comment: paste the code as is, then mark it and press Ctrl + K