# JQuery doubleclick listener in select - IE not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I seem to have a bit of trouble with Internet-Explorer once again...
The following code works fine in other browsers but IE doesn't like it at all!
It would be a simple double click listener for each option in a select.

Here's the simplified JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zoq8yo0s/1/

Any suggestions?

```
function registerClickListener() {
    $(".available-option").each(function(){
        $($(this)).dblclick(function(){
            alert("dblclick");
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: I think the click event in general on options in IE isn't supported.  You need to bind to it on the `<select>` instead.  [Reference here](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html)

Comment: @JamesThorpe I already tried the following workaround, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408714/double-click-using-ie
but that didn't work out...
and if you remove the <select> and only leave the options for themselves, the dblclick event works in IE as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the dblclick event to the select element its working,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectEl").dblclick(function () {
        alert("dblclick");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/zoq8yo0s/8/)

Comment: Why to select element instead of option?????

Comment: Why to add event to each option if element can provide its value?

Comment: Works so far, now trying to implement it in my scenario

Answer (score 0):

You could start a timer on the click of an element and wait for a while for the second click. If second click comes, clear the timer and run double click. If the second click doesn't come, then it is a single click.

Answer (score 0):

if .available-option is the id then use #available-option instead of .available-option
Hope will help u.

Comment: It's a `class` mate.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$(document).on("dblclick",".available-option", function (){
     //code here
 });
```

or you can do this :

```
$(document).on("dblclick",".available-option", myfunction);

function myfunction(){
  //code here
}
```

Comment: Explanation might help others to understand.